# Add images or Icons in the react-native-modal-selector

Tags: react-native

I created a modal using `react-native-modal-selector`, but there is not any props or method defined to add the Images or Icons in the `react-native-modal-selector` document. Is there any other way to add the Images or Icon in the `react-native-modal-selector`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as per docs :

```
[{
  key: 5,
  label: 'Red Apples',
  component: <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Red Apples custom component ☺</Text></View>
}]
```

Like have a field named component and add your data

Comment: Data is a dynamic type.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not as straightforward for this point, but after playing around a bit, this worked for me:

```
  let data = categories.map((category, index) => (
   {
     key: category.id,
     label: category.name,
     component: <View style={styles.row}><Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: category.icon }} /><Text>{category.name}</Text></View>,
     accessibilityLabel: category.name
    }))
```